# how to sync user data larger than 100 kb

Tags: google-chrome-extension, synchronization

in my chrome extension, user data saved into chrome.storage.local can easily go over 100 kb, which is limit for using storage.sync. fileSystem is limited for apps, so what is left for extensions to sync user data between devices?
*I know it's a broad question, but I need to start somewhere...*

Comment: Use an external server and sync the user ID/token to automatically authenticate with your server.

Comment: @RobW is there any examples/tutorials/articles/documentation how to do it?

Comment: To do what? Creating a backend? Generating user IDs/tokens? Sending requests to a server? It would surely help if you state what you already know and what you've tried.

Comment: @RobW any of those. I never played with users credentials, logins...and I'm sure I'm not the first that want's to offer data sync (to extension users) larger than storage.sync quota. I feel like I'm asking something very weird, am I?...

Comment: btw. I didn't tried anything so far...I was under impression that later( when I find time, and finish other stuff) I could easily use sync fileSystem...but later last night I realized that this is dead end...

Comment: Assuming that you don't want to build and maintain the server infrastructure yourself, you probably need an external provider. Take a look at https://www.firebase.com/ for example.

Comment: @RobW I see that it is a a payed service... is there a way to do it with gdrive/dropbox/skydrive? To simply sync storage values onChange with (usually) free user accounts? I don't have any financial benefits from my ext.

Comment: Firebase has a free plan. If you're willing to implement the synchronization logic yourself, then you can also use Drive, DropBox, OneDrive or any other cloud-storage of course.

Comment: @RobW ok :) we done 360°, is there any documentation or examples how to use gdrive/dropbox etc. for syncing chrome extension data..anything where to start from...?

Comment: I'm not aware of such documents, but if you search on the internet, you'll probably find them. You have to 1) use an external API to store/retrieve key-value pairs (easy) 2) come up with a conflict resolution method (when the same value has been modified on two devices) (not as easy) and 3) create/use a method to generate identifiers for associating the external datastore with your extension (easy).

Comment: This is getting kind of long but has useful comments. Google has a new paid service to store user data easily. Ive also used google spreadsheets which is easy using chrome.identity but user has to be signed in (otherwise roll your own oauth2 which isnt that hard)